# Reject SMTP login connections except ips on a white list

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

How to reject SMTP login connections on postfix from any IP except those on whitelist, (not rejecting the mail reception).

Tried adding to `main.cf` under

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
...
check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_access
...
```

Then adding IPs for the whitelist on `client_access` one IP per line like:

```
a.b.c.d/22 ok
```

Then did the `postmap` and `postfix` reload but it still allows clients using Thunderbird or similar to connect.

Running on Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/490761/how-to-only-accept-e-mail-from-a-single-ip-address

Maybe you forgot the *reject* in smtpd_recipient_restrictions?

Please note that the *reject* should be at the end of the line or after checking the *hash:/etc/postfix/client_access*.